# How can i display thousands of coordinates in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to build a map that shows protected forest but each polygon has at least 1000 coordinates and there are 20,000 polygons.

How can I display all these polygons in my app by using kotlin?

I have tried to store the coordinates in the Activity, as shown in the image below, but whenever i open the page, the app crash, seems like it cannot handle that much data in the Activity.

[image]

What is the solution to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep big text files in `src\main\assets\` directory and read them like this:

```
    val text = try {
        context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Failed to open asset file: $fileName", e)
    }
```

Comment: Great suggestion, it works! Thanks! If there is any more efficient solution, please share mate! Thanks!